# Mongoose times out and throws exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When node.js server is inactive for some time, it crashes with following exception:

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: failed to connect to [------] at null. (/Users/tomi/Documents/Platforms/Databox/Sources/Web/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:636:74)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
at null. (/Users/tomi/Documents/Platforms/Databox/Sources/Web/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:139:15)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket. (/Users/tomi/Documents/Platforms/Databox/Sources/Web/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:476:10)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:441:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

This is how I init the connection:

```
function connect(uri, poolsize, callback) {

var options = {
    db: { native_parser: false, retryMiliSeconds: 5000, numberOfRetries: 360000 },
    server: { poolSize: poolsize, socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 5000 },    auto_reconnect: true }
};
this.connection = mongoose.connect(uri, options).connection;

var addEvents = function (obj) {
    obj.on('connected', function () {
        console.log('Connected to database');
        //connectionPoolStats.logConnectionPoolStats();
    });
    obj.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log('Disconnected from database');
    });
    obj.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Connection to database closed');
    });
};
addEvents(this.connection);

if (callback) {
    callback();
}
```

};

The connection just throws exception and never reinitializes ;(

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

With which version of mongoose are you seeing this?

Please test with the new release available today: `npm install mongoose@3.6.17`.

If you continue to see this issue, please [open a ticket](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/issues/new).